# Adding rows to a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a plugin for jQuery. This is my first plugin, and I am stuck in the initial phase.

I need to do following things: I need to find the "add row" link from the table and bind to the click event. When the link is clicked, it should add a new row by cloning the existing template row. Initially the template row is hidden.

Following is the HTML.

```
<table id='grid1'>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#' id='add_row'>Add New Row</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id='data_table'>
                <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
                <tr id='template_row'>
                   <td><input type='text' /></td>
                   <td><input type='text' /></td>
                   <td><input type='text' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my jQuery so far:

```
(function($) {
  $.extend($.fn, {
    editableGrid: function() {
      function addRow() {
        //code to clone here but i need the instance of main table here ie grid1
      }
      this.find('#add_row').bind("click",addRow);
    }
  });   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Heh.  Sounds like a case of "Please write my entire plugin for me."

Comment: no i have given a try but i stuck in passing the arguments..

Comment: @Tomalak, never heard of jQuery homework lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going on from your current code:

```
(function($) {
  $.extend($.fn, {
    editableGrid: function() {
      this.find("a.add_row").click(function () {
        var $table  = $(this).parent("table").find("table.data_table");
        var $newRow = $table.find("tr.template_row").clone();

        $newRow.removeClass("template_row"); // !!!
        $table.append($newRow);
        return false;
      });
    }
  });   
})(jQuery);
```

Notes

- work with CSS classes instead of IDs - only that way you can have multiple "editable grids" on one page
- there is no benefit of using `bind()` over using `click()` here
- you can pass functions directly as arguments - no need to define them separately
- it can improve readability/clarity to use verbose selectors (`"a.add_row"` is better than just `".add_row"`)
- in the outer function, `this` refers to a jQuery object containing *all* matched elements, so `click()` binds all of them *in one step*.
- in the inner function, `this` refers to an individual DOM element (i.e. the clicked link) - it is *not* a jQuery object here!
- don't forget to return `false` from the `click` function to prevent the browser default behavior
- it's useful to prepend variables with a `$` to denote that they contain a jQuery object

Comment: thanks for the description :) .. and it worked now i am extending it for my use ..

Comment: @Ujjwal Good to hear! Also look into @DavidRodrigues' answer, the `detach()` suggestion he makes is a good way to further improve this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the template from the table and put it on a factory variable, like:

```
var factory = $('#template_row').detach();
factory.removeAttr('id'); // Suggestion for Tomalak
```

It will *hidden* (not really) from the table. Next step is bind click on your link and specify here will go the new factory.clone item. Like:

```
$('button.new-link').click(function(){
  $('#data_table').append(factory.clone(true));
});
```

**Take a look** too in [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: +1 for suggesting `detach()`. You just need to remove the id attribute from the "factory variable"/template.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a `plugin` just do this:

```
$('#add_row').click(function(){
     var clone = $('#template_row').clone();
     clone.removeAttr('id');
     clone.appendTo('#data_table');
})
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw5TF/

Comment: One-liner: `$('#data_table').append( $('#template_row').clone().removeAttr('id') );`

Comment: @Tomalak, yea thats true too :-P

Comment: I'm not a code golfer, usually, but this was too tempting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.myTableTingPlugin = function() {
  var self = this;

  $(self).find(".template_row").hide(); // or use css class
  $(this).find(".add_row").click(function() { 
     // shuld probebly not use ids if its a plugin 
     // so i use a class here

     var newRow =  $(self).find(".template_row").clone();
     $(self).find(".data_table").append(newRow);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use ids, classes are better. And double quotes are better too.

```
<table class="extendableTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="extendLink">Add New Row</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="data_table">
                <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
                <tr id='template_row'>
                   <td><input type="text" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Source code of the plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extendableTable = function(options){
        var table = this;
        this.find('.extendLink').click(function(){
            table.find('.dataTable .templateRow:first').clone().appendTo(table.find('.dataTable'));
            return false;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And then you can use plugin in such a way:

```
$('.extendableTable').extendableTable();
```